# Cookie Session not created after sucessfull login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

Hello so i have a MERN stack project, in this project user can register and login. After user sucessfully login, a session with cookie will created. But im having a problem, the user is logged in but no cookie is created. What do i do wrong ? I use the same exact logic in my other project, but the result is fine.

Login.js

```
const { emailLog, setEmailLog } = useContext(EmailUser)
  const [ passwordLog, setPasswordLog  ] = useState("")

  const handleClick = () => setShow(!show)

  const isError = emailLog === ''

  const login =  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    Axios.post("https://anydomain.com/login" , {
      email: emailLog, 
      password: passwordLog
    }).then((response)=> {
      if (response.data.result.email) {
        setEmailLog(response.data.result.email);  
        alert("Succes")
        setTimeout(() => navigate("/home"), 1000);
      } 
    });
  };
```

indexjs

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  cookie:{
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge:10 * 10 * 24 * 60
         },
  key: process.env.COOKIE_KEY,
  store: new MemoryStore({
      checkPeriod: 86400000 // prune expired entries every 24h
  }),
  secret: 'subscribe',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: false,
  }));

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password).then((passwordCheck) => {

            if(!passwordCheck) {
              return res.status(400).send({
                message: "Passwords does not match",
                error,
                result,
              });
            }
            const token = jwt.sign(
                {
                  userId: user._id,
                  userEmail: user.email,
                },
                "RANDOM-TOKEN",
                { expiresIn: "24h" }
              );

            const result = {email : user.email}
            req.session.email = result
            const role = user.role
            req.session.role = role
            res.status(200).send({
                message: "Login Successful",
                email: user.email,
                result,
                role,
                token
            });
            }).catch((error) => {
                res.status(400).send({
                message: "Passwords does not match",
                error
            });
            });
            }).catch((e) => {
                res.status(404).send({
                message: "Email not found",
                e,
        });
    });
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {

    if(req.session.email) {
        res.send({loggedIn: true, email: req.session.email, role : req.session.role })
    } else {
        res.send({loggedIn: false})
    }

  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code I don't see the `cookie` method of `res`, which helps set the cookie in Express.js, for more info you can refer: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie

Also I'd say, it's in some cases very tough to find out where is the real problem when it comes to setting cookies. If the code you use in your current project is the same with working code in another project, you can check versions of the packages, e.g. jwt or Express.js.

But the easiest way to understand on which side the problem is happening is the inspecting response headers which are set by Express.js. If you see the `set-cookie` header (with value you expect) after successfully login in your XHR network requests list of your browser `Dev Tools`, that means you should do research to find the source of the issue in the front-end side code. Then, `document.cookie` can help you see the all cookies that your app can access through your javascript code.